# Unable to load rss feeds from packaged chrome application

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am trying to get rss feed from a packaged chrome application but I am getting the error below.

undefined
angular.js:8642 Refused to load the script 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&callback=a….callbacks._0&q=http%3A%2F%2...%2Frss%2Fheadlines.php' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

What am I doing wrong